# How can I send a WhatsApp verification to users by Custom WhatsApp API Integration?

Tags: twilio, whatsapp, verification

I am working on implementing a custom WhatsApp API integration to send verification codes to users on WhatsApp. I have already been approved for access to the WhatsApp Business API and obtained the necessary credentials.

Now, I want to send verification codes to users through WhatsApp using my custom integration. But I don't have any idea that how to do that?

I just wanna know **How do I generate a random verification code in my application without getting any bugs?**

And also I wanna know **Which WhatsApp API endpoints should I use to send the verification code as a text message?**

I was expecting a the most suitable way to do these things without getting any bugs

Comment: _"How do I generate a random verification code in my application without getting any bugs?"_ - the heart of your question is _entirely unrelated_ to WhatsApp or Twilio, and has a trivial solution: use a cryptographically-secure random-number generator to select n-many characters from a small alphabet of digit charactres, or for greater security: from an alphabet of nonhomoglyphic and nonhomophonous characters (using a custom alphabet avoids ambiguity when read-out: e.g. `I` vs `1` vs `l`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by using [Twilio Verify](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api). The advantage here is that you don't need to generate and manage your own codes and can even use the one of Twilio's numbers:

**Step 1: [Create a verify service](https://console.twilio.com/us1/develop/verify/services)**

**Step 2: [Send a code to a number](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/whatsapp)**

```js
// Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
// and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.verify.v2.services('VAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
                .verifications
                .create({to: '+15017122661', channel: 'whatsapp'})
                .then(verification => console.log(verification.accountSid));
```

**Step 3: Verify the code the user entered**

```js
client.verify.v2.services('VAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
                .verificationChecks
                .create({to: '+15017122661', code: '123456'})
                .then(check => console.log(check.valid));
```

Comment: yeah wow it's very easy to manage

Comment: I'm glad you like it. Feel free to mark this answer as correct (checkmark button) if it helped you.